# google app engine deployment files limit per directory

Tags: google-app-engine

I got the following error message while deploying my app:

```
...
07:45 AM Scanned 5500 files.
...
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Exceeded the limit of 1000 for allowable files per directory within gaelibs/romn/cscd/
--- end server output ---
```

but in the [document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Quotas_and_Limits) it says:

```
maximum total number of files (app files and static files) 10,000 per directory 10,000 total
```

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [issue 9256](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9265) opened by me. Now Google guys change the limit from 10,000 to 1,000.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're running the latest version of the SDK. I was not aware of this change, I thought the limit was still 1000. So if it says 10000 it means the limit was raised and it can have been introduced in a later version of the SDk than the version that you're using.

Comment: I am using the latest version of SDK, and I uploaded similar amount of files several days ago without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you can get around the 1000 file limit by creating subdirectories.  For example, if you have 1500 files in one directory Google will complain.  If you divvy up those files into, let's say 500 files each for 3 new subdirectories, Google won't complain.  You still have 1500 files in one directory, sort of.

This was a lot easier for me than migrating everything to gcs.